# TreeView Context Menu Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to put a context menu on to the treeview items. Which i could achieve like this

```
 <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Nodes}">
                    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                        <TextBlock  Padding="15,0,30,0" Text="{Binding Path=numitems}" TextAlignment="Right"  DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
                        <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Path=Text}" DockPanel.Dock="Left" TextAlignment="Left">
                             <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                          <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Header="Rename" />
                            <MenuItem Header="Exlcude"/>

                          </ContextMenu>
    </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                        </TextBlock> 
                    </DockPanel>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

What i am trying to achieve is 1)When they click on Rename we should be able to rename the treeview item 2)When they click on exclude that should open up a new context menu on exclude with the tree view item values. Each treeview item is a comma seperated value for ex: Rav4,corolla,Camry,.. so when they click on exclude this should open a context much with three items. I am using MVVM. So How to pass this value to my view model.second thing is instead of Hard coded values i wanted to bind a enum or array to the context menu Instead of Hard coding Any ideas or code samples are appreciated

Graphical Representation:

```
Toyota,Corolla,Camry---->Rename
                        Exclude---> Toyota
                                    corolla
                                    Camry
```

Comment: I'm hunting for this too, I'll update your answer if I solve it!